# Python, saving the last 3 scores to file

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
current_class = Classes[student_class] #Used to get the value of the key in Classes
class_score = open(current_class, 'a+') #Scores must be appended and not written to avoid overwriting data
class_format = (name + ' scored ' + str(Score) + '\n') #This is the format in which the text file will save the data as
class_score.write(class_format) #Writing the scores to the text file using the format above
class_read = class_score.read() #For some reason, the scores will not be added to the text file unless I add this text (Using OSX)
```

I use this code to save the scores of (input name) to a text file. There are 3 text files and depending on what class you are in (user inputs class), it saves the score to either class 1, 2 or 3.

However, this process could be repeated 1000 times and if the name inputted is the same 'Name' could have 1000 scores. How would I limit it so when appending the score onto the txt file it saves only the 3 most recent scores

EDIT: I've developed the code a little, still no idea how to get it to replace the 'oldest' score however.

```
current_class = Classes[student_class] #Used to get the value of the key in Classes
class_score = open(current_class, 'a+') #Scores must be appended and not written to avoid overwriting data
class_format = (name + ' scored ' + str(Score) + '\n') #This is the format in which the text file will save the data as
class_read = class_score.read()
class_count = class_read.count(name)
while True:
    if class_count > 3:

    else:
        class_score.write(class_format) #Writing the scores to the text file using the format above
        break
```

Comment: You will either read the file every time a new score is about to be written and the scores analysed. Or you could keep all stores in a memory datastructure, put the current score into it based on your logic, and then overwrite the file with the current scores.

Comment: You could start an sqlite database, and make a function to dumb the database.

Comment: @Snuggert looking at sqlite databases right now, will get back to you

Comment: Pass `0` for the `buffering` argument of open to get write to flush every time.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to limit the file to only the last three scores, then before you write to the file, open it for reading and read/parse the previous three scores.

```
class_score = open(current_class, 'r')
prev_scores = []
for line in class_score:
  prev_scores.append(line)

class_score.close()
class_score = open(current_class, 'w')
for p in prev_scores[1:]:
  class_score.write(p)

class_score.write(class_format)
```

Comment: I've implemented this into my code, however after testing I found some errors. I've changed the 'w' to 'a+' because I don't want to overwrite the whole file, also my python doesn't seem to write unless I include 'class_score.read()' underneath the write function. Also, when the third score is added, the second score is repeated so it shows 4 scores instead of 3. EDIT: it seems this code only seems to work for 'one person' however the user can input their name so we can assume if a user uses two different names it is two different people

Comment: So by changing 'w' to 'a+' you change the functionality of the program. The 'w' erases the previous file and re-writes it. By appending ('a+') you are leaving some of the previous data so there will be multiple copies of newly inserted data.

Comment: class_score.read() reads the entire file. Since you aren't assigning it to a variable, that data just goes away. Your python should be same as everyone elses. After you write, either call class_score.close() or let the script end and the writes should be committed to the file as desired.

Comment: The user's name is part of class_format. I didn't add the definition of class_format to my code snippet above.